# AS3 Camera selection

Tags: actionscript-3

Has anyone build a AS3 Camera-Select-algorithm, ready to use?

With MacBooks you have the problem that the build-in webcam is not rightly choosen from the webplayer.
You have to select the USP-Cam by youself from the list

DV Video
IIDC FireWire Video
USB Video Class Video

by

```
camera = Camera.getCamera("2");
```

THNX!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found kind of a workaround [here](http://sanderkruger.blogspot.com/2007/02/working-with-cameras-in-as3.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cant actually set the camera programatically.  The best you can do is prompt the user to set it next to a video panel to show them if the camera they've chosen actually works. example here: http://www.neave.com/webcam/

to prompt them to change cameras you use:
`Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.CAMERA)`

there is no event to wait for, though you can poll your video panel's bitmap data for changes and prompt the user behind the security panel when you think they've chosen the right camera.

Comment: This is not true. See headkit's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Having done battle with this problem, I would suggest that everyone use this library.

https://github.com/cataclysmicrewind/CameraDetection/

Flash + webcam should = easy + awesome. 
Unfortunately, it is pain + suffering.